# Sharing login-system between classic ASP and ASP.Net

Tags: asp.net, security, asp-classic

A client uses classic ASP to log in to their web based backoffice.

I have written a new ASP.Net app to be included in the backoffice, and I need to utilize the already existing login-system, so that when they are logged in there, they don't need to log in again in the new ASP.Net app.

Logins and passwords are stored as clear text in a SQL Server db, that I can access from my ASP.Net app.

What would be an effective way to integrate these systems?

My current best idea is:
In the link to my ASP.Net app, I link to a "gateway" login-page with their userid and a hashed password + common secret in the querystring. I then compare this to the password of the user in the database... But the problem is, that if this querystring is intercepted, it can be used to access the asp.net site, without actually knowing the username and password...

I am most likely overlooking something simple.

Comment: If you put hashes in the querystring they need to be timed out, i.e you also append the date and time when it expires, and send along that too. Sure they could still use that but at least it times out.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think your idea is on the right path.

As you probably already know, classic asp and asp.net cannot share the same session state, so you do need to have a mechanism to log from one into the other.

What I would do is: when someone logs in, create a unique GUID that you save in the database for that user. When you jump from one site to the other, pass that GUID into the query string. When you try to auto-log them into the other site, look up that GUID and see if it's attached to anyone. If it is, log them in.

This way you aren't passing anything that a user could guess or decrypt.

Comment: If you are going to save a value in the database in ASP and compare that value in ASP.NET code, why not save a boolean flag indicating logged-in status, instead ?

Comment: Because the point is to auto log them in from one environment into the next. If you log into the asp.net side, and then go to the asp side. there is no way of know who that person is on the asp side automatically. Setting a flag on the database doesn't help you at all in this case. By saving the GUID, you can look up which person belongs to the GUID and then auto-log them into either environment.

Comment: As "Zhaph - Ben Duguid" says in a comment to Rob's answer below, you can quasi-share session state between .NET and Classic ASP.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479313.aspx  We've been doing it for 4 years.  Passing a GUID, or anything else, on a GET or a POST leaves you open to spoofing and session hijacking by someone with a packet sniffer, unless you're using SSL.

Comment: This is what I ended up implemented, and it has run in production for almost 2 years now. Works perfectly.

Answer (score 4):

How does the classic ASP system maintain login state? "Piggy-backing" off that would be your best bet, by far.

All classic ASP systems I've worked on have used cookies for tracking authentication information, so just read those and compare against the database that you can access.

---

As the information is stored in a Classic ASP session, could you add a "redirect page" to the classic ASP side of things that is the "entrance" to the new module, and cause this to write the useful data out as cookies, or trigger a POST to your start page? By using cookies or a POST request, you minimise your worry about having the url "hijacked" allowing someone to get into the ASP.net site without username/password.

Comment: They use session - and that cannot be shared between ASP and ASP.Net (as far as I know).

Looking at the cookies, when I am logged into their admin system, I get a cookie for the session called "ASPSESSIONxxxxxxxxxxx" that contains some string of nonsense "DBHPNPCDKCJHOMHDPFOHEDPA".

So the piggybacking on cookies seems out of the question.

Comment: I agree with Rob, a redirection scheme is probably what you'll end up with since .NET can't check the session state of the ASP site directly. This method will also have the advantage of working over different domains, however it isn't simple to make it secure.

If you care about security you should be very careful of how you validate/invalidate the data passed between the sites. You don't want to end up with a system where you can login by guessing or replaying an URL. For example, SAML redirection uses certificates on each side of the redirect to make the passed data secure.

Comment: Sharing Session State between ASP and ASP.NET: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479313.aspx

Answer (score 2):

You are rightly worried about a MITM type attack, possibly through DNS cache poisoning or similar. Depending on your circumstances, it may be enough to mitigate the potential effects of this by adding a time constraint to the login token that is passed across the application boundaries.

The 'GUID in the database approach' is something I have used successfully myself in the past, both for passing users between two applications sharing the same authentication database, and also for 'password reset email' type scenarios. You could 'expire' this by having an additional column on the record specifying the date at which the GUID was added, and modifying your application code to only log in GUID auths which are less than x minutes / hours / days old.

An alternative could be to avoid additional fields in the database by concatenating something like:

```
UserId + [Value representing current time to nearest x minute / hour /day] + Salt
```

.. hashing it, then then duplicating your algorithm on the other application and comparing the two generated values.

In general, I think your proposed solution is appropriate to the problem. It is certainly not too complicated.

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't you submit it via Form and not through the Querystring? That would eliminate the possibility of it being intercepted in the url.

Comment: Intercepting/abusing post is only marginally harder than get, isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

If interception is a serious issue then you need to be running the site over HTTPS.  Otherwise using the UserID + Nonce that is then hashed by the password is reasonably strong.

Alternatively you could get the ASP app to add a GUID session cookie once logon has been acheived and store that GUID in a DB table.  Your ASP.NET can look up the GUID from the cookie to see if logon has been acheived.  If you include the ASP session cookie value in the table you can make reasonably sure that the current ASP session is the same session that was used when the GUID was created.