# How can I create check cookie VB Server Side Script that will work in both classic ASP and VB.NET pages?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, asp-classic

I am trying to create a check cookie server side script that will work in both Classic ASP pages and VB.NET pages. I have been unsuccessful. Example below:

```
<% If Request.Cookies("login-id") = "" Then Response.Redirect("login.asp") %>
```

This works on my Classic ASP pages, but in .NET, it throws an error because when there is no cookie, it throws an exception because it can't read a cookie that doesn't exist.

Is there a way for me to craft the script in a way that would work in both Classic and VB.NET?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Sharing login-system between classic ASP and ASP.Net](https://stackoverflow.com/a/921575)

Comment: This is not a duplicate of my question. I do not want to share cookies across different domains. It's all on same domain.

Comment: The principles are the same regardless you want to share a cookie between applications. As you didn’t make it clear that the sites weren’t cross domain, what do you expect?

Comment: I can set a cookie on Classic ASP and read it in .NET applications and vice versa with no issues. So I'm not sure why this wasn't work.